# Only registered user can access to certain web. Check on the privilege code

Tags: php, syntax, privileges

I want to set only login user can access to certain webpage. This is my privilege.php file. But when I put require 'privilege.php' at the beginning of the page I want to, it return access_denied page even the user is login. How ?

Is there any example of privilege syntax I can use apart of this one in case this one is wrong ?

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Check whether the session variable username is present or not
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || (($_SESSION['username']) == '')) {
        header("location: access_denied.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: make sure you are setting $_SESSION['username'] to the username if they are successfully logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

```
session_start();
```

at the beginning in every file where you want to check session?

Answer (score 0):

In your login page, you should set a session variable that the user is logged in.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION["logged_in"] = "yes";
```

When you want to check if the user is logged in, check if that variable is set to "yes".

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["logged_in"]) && $_SESSION["logged_in"] == "yes") {
   echo "welcome back, you're logged in.";
} else {
   die(header("Location: access_denied.php"))
}
```

Comment: It returns to access_denied page all the time even the user is logged in. I've putted session_start();

$_SESSION["logged_in"] = "yes"; in my checklogin page.